# Non-commercial long 7 day retreats in Japan?

Tags: japan, accommodation

I'm looking for long and serious meditation retreats in Japan, at least 7 days (to 15/30 days). I know about Shukubo's but they appear more like a holiday with 2-3 hours of meditation, and most I found seemed commercial (charging much more than what a non-profit would).

I know about Goenka Vipassana obviously, but would be surprised if there are absolutely no other options with daily 7-8 hours of meditation for a week or more given that Buddhism is widespread in Japan.

EDIT: After @jpatokal's answer: While english instructions is definitely a plus, I'm happy to know about centers with Japanese only instructions too.

Comment: Just a small nitpick, "Shinto is the largest religion in Japan, practiced by nearly 80% of the population" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shinto)

Comment: @MarkMayo Pretty major "nit" actually. Thanks for the correction. I rephrased my question so as not to propagate false information.

Comment: Actually, according to a famous survey, Japan is 80% Shinto *and* 80% Buddhist...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I presume you're looking specifically for *English-language* retreats, which narrows your options significantly; Japan may have a lot of temples, but it doesn't have all that many that can run a week-long course in a foreign language.  (Even if the vast majority of that course involves complete silence!)

But have no fear, Wikivoyage's [Meditation in Japan](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Meditation_in_Japan) is here, and suggests the following:

- [Sogenji](http://onedropzen.org/community/japan/sogenji), Okayama.  Week-long sesshins in English several times a year.
- [Toshoji](http://homepage3.nifty.com/toshoji/), Tokyo.  5-day retreats twice a year.

Poking around on the Soto Zen website's [list of temples open to foreign visitors](http://global.sotozen-net.or.jp/eng/temples/foreigner/index.html) may also find something interesting.

Comment: Thanks. English is definitely great, though I'd like to know about Japanese language centers too if you already know about them.

Comment: So I checked out more and Sogenji Sesshins are only for meditators who commit themselves indefinitely. You can not attend a single Sogenji Sesshin.